# Problema con consulta equipos migrados window server 2016

Tags: windows-server, directorioactivo

Que tal, me encuentro con un pequeño problema, tengo un window server 2016, sobre el cual ya se han migrado todos los usuarios, he tratado de consultar los equipos que se han logueado, pero no se, si existe forma de consultar cuantos usuarios se han migrado, estén en linea o no, es esto posible?

Saludos

Comment: Creo que necesitas agregar más información para poder responder tu pregunta, ¿Utilizas Active Directory o cuentas locales del servidor? ¿Qué significa que los usuarios se hayan migrado?

Comment: Es Active Directory, migrados significa que configure maquinas con las respectivas cuentas de Active Directory

Comment: Entonces tienes un dominio de Active Directory y sobre dicho dominio agregaste equipos y cuentas de usuario. Ahora te interesa saber los usuarios que han iniciado sesión desde dichos equipos en Active Directory ¿es así?